# Video Qos Profiling Tool

Tags: video, video-streaming

Is there any open source tool that could capture the video streams delay, jitters, frame loss,... Some open source analytics for video.

Reza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. we could use Wireshark for monitoring the performance.

http://wiki.wireshark.org/RTP